# Intent extras return null in my application

Tags: android, android-intent, extra

I want to parse location information from maps in my Maps class to another `Activity` and `setText()` for `EditText` but my intent extra returns `null`. 
First, I click a button in second class then I go to maps in maps activity. Finally, I want to parse location from maps to second activity.

Maps Class:

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        LatLng location= mMarker.getPosition();
        double longitude= location.longitude;
        double latitude=location.latitude;
        List<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude , longitude , 1);
            String adresse = addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String country = addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
            String fulladr = adresse +" , "+country;
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, fulladr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,Partierendezvous.class);
            i.putExtra("result",fulladr.toString().trim());
            setResult(Partierendezvous.RESULT_OK,i);
            finish();
```

And Second Class:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("result");
    edlieurend.setText(value);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Lieu not found " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that the `geocoder.getFromLocation()` can return an empty result or even `null`. Therefore, it is better practice to check the results before trying to directly access the first entry. In other words, do not try to use `addressList.get(0)` without checking if `addressList` is not `null` or if the length is zero. Also the documents suggest that you call `getFromLocation()` from a background thread: "It may be useful to call this method from a thread separate from your primary UI thread."

Answer (score 0):

Your question could benefit from some more details. If you want to deliver results from the Maps activity to the second activity then you need to use [`startActivityForResult`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) to start the Maps activity.

Second Activity

```
private static final int PICK_LOCATION_REQUEST = 1;

private void pickLocation() {
    .
    .
    startActivityForResult(mapsIntent, PICK_LOCATION_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_LOCATION_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a location.
            // The Intent's data should contain the location you set before finishing the Maps Activity
            String value = data.getString("result");
            edlieurend.setText(value);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Lieu not found " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the information in the put extra , i want to settext from edit text but return null ,

Comment: Check out my edited answer, is that what you are after?

Comment: the picklocation in any class i write this

Comment: In the activity with the `TextView`